# Pali Patimokkha versions and recital

Tags: monasticism, vinaya

Is there a standardized version of Pali Patimokkha to be memorized?

Is there a difference in the recital of the Pali Patimokkha among the monks?

Answer (score 0):

For a [Pali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pali) recital of the [Bhikkhu Patimokkha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81%E1%B9%ADimokkha), together with romanized Pali subtitles, please see [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/M7mKBHOD-Zg) by [Ven. Ariyadhammika](https://sasanarakkha.org/2018/08/30/ariyadhammika/). The pronunciation here is perfectly clear.

Please see the book [Analysis of the Patimokkha](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9552404053) by Ven. Nanatusita for the romanized Pali version, a translation of each rule and a word-by-word analysis. There are online versions [here](https://www.bps.lk/olib/bp/bp627s_Nyanatusita_Bhikkhu-Patimokkha-Translation.pdf) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FtZcbx4Mf3on9tHYFRN0FAmrm-1bM21W/view).

For a romanized Pali version of the Patimokkha without the translation, please see [Bhikkhupātimokkhapāḷi](https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Buddhist-Texts/V6-Patimokkha-BJT/index.htm) compiled by Ven. Anandajoti.

An English translation by [Ven. Thanissaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%B9%ACh%C4%81nissaro_Bhikkhu) can be found here: [Bhikkhu Pāṭimokkha: The Bhikkhus' Code of Discipline](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/vin/sv/bhikkhu-pati.html).